# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
public class Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);}}
```

** FileResponse **

```
public class FileResponse {
private String name;
private String uri;
private String type;
private long size;

public FileResponse(String name, String uri, String type, long size) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setUri(uri);
    this.setType(type);
    this.setSize(size);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUri() {
    return uri;
}

public void setUri(String uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public long getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(long size) {
    this.size = size;
}

// getters and setters removed for the sake of brevity
```

}

**StorageProperties**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "storage")
```

public class StorageProperties {

```
private String location;

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

**StorageService**

```
@Service
```

public interface StorageService {

```
void init();

String store(MultipartFile file);

Stream<Path> loadAll();

Path load(String filename);

Resource loadAsResource(String filename);

void deleteAll();
```

}

** FileSystemStorageService **

@Service
public class FileSystemStorageService implements StorageService {

```
private final Path rootLocation;

@Autowired
public FileSystemStorageService(StorageProperties properties) {
    this.rootLocation = Paths.get(properties.getLocation());
}

@Override
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(rootLocation);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Could not initialize storage location", e);
    }
}

@Override
public String store(MultipartFile file) {
    String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    try {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file " + filename);
        }
        if (filename.contains("..")) {
            // This is a security check
            throw new StorageException(
                    "Cannot store file with relative path outside current directory "
                            + filename);
        }
        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(inputStream, this.rootLocation.resolve(filename),
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Failed to store file " + filename, e);
    }

    return filename;
}

@Override
public Stream<Path> loadAll() {
    try {
        return Files.walk(this.rootLocation, 1)
                .filter(path -> !path.equals(this.rootLocation))
                .map(this.rootLocation::relativize);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
    }

}

@Override
public Path load(String filename) {
    return rootLocation.resolve(filename);
}

@Override
public Resource loadAsResource(String filename) {
    try {
        Path file = load(filename);
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
        if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
            return resource;
        }
        else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    "Could not read file: " + filename);
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read file: " + filename, e);
    }
}

@Override
public void deleteAll() {
    FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(rootLocation.toFile());
}
```

}
** FileNotFoundException **

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

public class FileNotFoundException extends StorageException {

```
public FileNotFoundException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public FileNotFoundException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
}
```

}

**StorageException**

public class StorageException extends RuntimeException {

```
public StorageException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public StorageException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
}
```

}

**page HTML**
``
     
   
    
    **Company Logo**
    
     
      
         Browse… 
         
        
       
       
      
       Try selecting a *text* file to upload.
     
     
      
     
    
     **Company Name**
     
      
      
     
     **Company Address**
     
      
      
     
     **Company Phone**
     
      
      
     
     **CIO Name**
     
       
      
     
      **CIO Email** 
     
       
      
     
      **CIO Phone** 
     
      
      
     
     **Technical Name**
     
       
      
     
     **Technical Email** 
     
       
      
     
     **Technical Phone** 
     
       
      
     
     **Country Company**
     
      
      
     
     **City Company**
     
      
      
     
     **Industry**
     
      
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
      
      
     
      **VIP**
     
      
         
         
      
      
     
     
    
   
    Save
    Annuler

**CustomerController**

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerrepository; 

@RequestMapping(value="/customer_manage")
public String AllCustomer(Model model, Customer customer) {

    List<Customer> custs = customerrepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("cust", custs);
    model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    model.addAttribute("totalCustomer", custs.size());

    return "customer_manage";
}
 @Autowired
 private StorageService storageService;

    public CustomerController(StorageService storageService) {
        this.storageService = storageService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String listAllFiles(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("files", storageService.loadAll().map(
                path -> ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                        .path("/download/")
                        .path(path.getFileName().toString())
                        .toUriString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        return "listFiles";
    }

    @GetMapping("/download/{filename:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String filename) {

        Resource resource = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                        "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload-file")
    @ResponseBody
    public FileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String name = storageService.store(file);

        String uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/download/")
                .path(name)
                .toUriString();

        return new FileResponse(name, uri, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }
   /* @PostMapping("/upload-multiple-files")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<FileResponse> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
        return Arrays.stream(files)
                .map(file -> uploadFile(file))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } */

@RequestMapping(value="/SaveCustomer" , method= RequestMethod.POST)
private String SaveCustomer(@Valid Customer addCust, BindingResult bindingResult) {//, @RequestParam(name="picture")MultipartFile file
        addCust.setStatus("Actif");
        customerrepository.save(addCust);

    return "redirect:/customer_manage"; 
}

@RequestMapping(value ="updateCustomerform" )
private String updateCustomerform( Model model, Integer id ) {
    Customer customer = customerrepository.getOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("customer",customer);
    System.out.println(customer.getName());
    return "updateCustomerForm";            
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/editCustomer",method= RequestMethod.POST)
private String updateCustomer(@Valid Customer addCust, BindingResult bindingResult) {//, @RequestParam(name="picture")MultipartFile file
        addCust.setStatus("Actif");
        customerrepository.save(addCust);
    return "redirect:/customer_manage";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/detailCustomer")
public String detailCustomer( Model model, Integer id ) {
    Customer customer = customerrepository.getOne(id);
     model.addAttribute("customer",customer);
     System.out.println(customer.getName());    
        return "detailCust";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/archiverCustomer" )
private String archiverCustomer( Model model, Integer id ) {
    Customer Cust = customerrepository.getOne(id);
    Cust.setStatus("Archived");
    customerrepository.save(Cust);

    return "redirect:/customer_manage";         
}
```

}

**application.properties**

`
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB

spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB`enter code here`

storage.location=./uploads         `

**error**
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController' defined in file [D:\STAGEPFEPowerM\Spring\TEST5\PMP2.2\target\classes\com\example\demo\controllers\CustomerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSystemStorageService' defined in file [D:\STAGEPFEPowerM\Spring\TEST5\PMP2.2\target\classes\com\example\demo\exception\FileSystemStorageService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.exception.FileSystemStorageService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 18: ./uploads

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow. please go through the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show the code of FileSystemStorageService. There is a InvalidPathException thrown in the constructor

Comment: Mr. @SimonMartinelli